# Passing ng-repeat value into Ionic Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an `ng-repeat` for an array of users, and I want to be able to click on each user to display their detailed profile information in an Ionic Modal.

Here's the actual HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='user in users track by $index' ng-click="openModal()">
  <div class="col">
     <div class="col profile-image" >
         <img src="img/default_user.jpg" class="connect_image" /><br />{{user.name}}<br />
         <span class="connect_subject">{{user.about}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's a sample Modal inside that template:

```
<script id="profile-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
   <div class="modal">
      <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">{{user.name}}</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
   </div>
</script>
```

The question is, how do I pass the `ng-repeat` user variable into the modal, so I can access `user.name`?

Comment: can you provide `openModal` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to apply the OpenModal() function to a particualr user, here is the code

```
 <div ng-repeat='user in users track by $index' >
          <div class="col">
            <div class="col profile-image" ng-click="openModal(user)">
              <img src="img/default_user.jpg" class="connect_image" />
              <br />{{user.name}}
              <br />
              <span class="connect_subject">{{user.about}}</span>
            </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

And in function you can apply to the scope,

```
 $scope.openModal = function(user) {   
          $scope.user = user;
          $scope.modalCtrl.show();
        };
```

Here is the working [`Codepen`](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/GpGBXq?editors=101)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $scope of parent controller to [modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) controller like that;

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
});
```

Then you can use your parent scope's data in modal controller. And I saw now. You want to pass your user data that is in ngRepeat to modal controller.

In this case, your code should be the following;

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.openModal = function(data) {
    $scope.selectedUser = data;
    $scope.modal.show();
}
```

Then, you can use your selected user data with selectedUser.

And you can take a look [that](http://codepen.io/gnomeontherun/pen/crbtA?editors=101).